# MVC form not going to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc, so am still struggling with some concepts.
I have a very simple form and controller. 
Controller:

```
    public class InquiryController : BaseController {

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Search(int Id) {

         int newid = Id;

        return View();

    }
}
```

and the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Results", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("id", null, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", style = "width: 200px" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

What is happening is that when I enter a number in the form, I want that number to be passed to the "Search" function in the controller. I do not understand how to get the form to call the controller and do its processing inside that controller. Instead, it goes to an error looking for the "results" page, which i understand comes from the BeginForm method.
So in essence, how can i get my form to pass the number entered into the search box to my controller function?

Comment: Why you have such a random code in your sample - clearly you've checked [BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) documentation that says that arguments are `(actionName, controllerName...)` yet you sample code shows some totally unrelated values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify what action and what controller you want to go to in the first two arguments of `Html.BeginForm`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Inquiry", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("id", null, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", placeholder = "Harvest Tag, 6 Digit Tag No.", style = "width: 200px" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Inside the action you can access the Id like you're doing but you could also get it from `FormCollection["id"]` or `Request["id"]` as the original string and validate it to avoid getting parsing errors in case the user submits an invalid int.

Comment: And you should add the [HttpPost] attribute to the Search method in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to [`BeginForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) is the action to take, and the second is the controller to execute, so your usage should be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Inquiry", FormMethod.Post))
```

The value that gets passes in is found (in this case) by the HTML ID of the input control (`id`)